# How do I force shoot in Jagged Alliance: Back in Action

Tags: jagged-alliance-bia

In one of the tips on the loading screens in Jagged Alliance: Back in Action, I says that some materials that don't allow a line of sight can be penetrated by bullets and that I should command my men to force shoot. How do I force shoot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.quartertothree.com/game-talk/showthread.php?t=65149&page=13) you can force shoot two ways:

> 1. With the F key you can force to shoot to the mouse cursor point and use the line drawn to check LoF.
> 2. You can also force fire by clicking on the weapon icon and then clicking where you want to shoot and see LOF that way as well.